# Can not install a database, can I still learn though?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, in-memory-database

I am given access to a domain where I can put my code in and it will go public, like in this [example](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~std10093/cageResults.php). In order to store the data right now, I am using PHP and I write the data to a file. When the page is loaded, I will read from file and display it in the page.

However, for teaching purposes, I would like to use a database, but I have no privileges, which would allow me to install a database. So, can I do something, that would still allow me to learn how to use a database && apply it to my page?

A negative answer would also be accepted.

---

I thought of [SQLite in-memory](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), but it says that the database will delete itself, once the connection to the database is closed. What does that mean exactly? It means that it will delete itself when the user exits the page from his browser? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849679/temporary-in-memory-database-in-sqlite) gives me this feeling.

Comment: Get [sql server express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx). and install it on a test server / local pc / whatever. Why pollute your current production environment with an experiment?

Comment: I am a student, so I am not polluting anything. I want to put the database where I have my page, so that I work on that. I can not install anything there though @Reaces :/

Comment: Depending upon your institution they should (if you need to do web development) have a small area set aside for you to play around with essentially, speak to your tutor they should know where that is, or alternatively find the DBA tutor, they'll know where it is how to access and potentially be able to set you up if you don't already have access (if they have the time)

Comment: @SteBov I have e-mailed them, but got nothing. The courses start next month, so I just wanted to play around now, that's why I am asking!

Comment: There is a chance that they're not in the office, (they need to take their holidays too), if you can get into your institution it may be worth seeing who is around and seeing people in person, education staff can be quite busy this time of year making sure everything is ready and organised. The IT support team (which should always be manned) may also know where you need to go to find out the details (Or at east point you in the correct direction). if not @reaces 's suggestion of just installing sql express is a good way to go

Comment: Nothing to lose @Reaces, so go on with the answer! Well, that's great for you!! No worries of course!

Comment: @gsamaras There you go, I wouldn't call it great though, be thankful that you're getting a formal education, it only gets harder afterwards ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to learn about SQL-Server is to install a [SQL Server express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx).

Even without having an actual website attached to it, Microsoft [has a few samples](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/).
And if you want live environment to try out, and see what you can put together, [Azure has a free trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/).
Which you can use to set up a few vm's.

It's very hard to learn anything from a limited environment, every problem or fault might or might not be caused by something you have control over.
If you want to get the most out of it, set up your own environment.
Or contact whoever is in charge of your environment to see what can be arranged.